# How can i provide a delete URL to a message to the user in slack?

Tags: slack

I want my bot to post a message to a user which has a "delete" link to a particular message posted by that user. For e.g.

"Hi @someuser , you have posted an inappropriate message. Click >>here<< to delete it."

When the user clicks on "here" it will open up the slack delete message UI?

I have the message ts and channel ID.
I know i can do this via chat.delete api call (have the link point to my backend and then issue the chat.delete api call). 
But i was wondering if there is a way to point user to the "delete message" window via a direct link in the message itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add to or change the existing message of another user. Only delete a message (with admin rights).

What you can do though is send the guy a direct message from your app including the link (or button) to delete the message. Just send a message to the user ID of the user via [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

Or you can send the guy an ephemeral message into the channel, that only he will be able to see with `chat.postEphermal`.

To create a user experience similar to Slack's delete pop-up for messages I would suggest the following:

1. Include a "Delete" button in your message to the user with the
   `danger` style, so it is shown in red color.
2. Include a [confirmation pop-up](https://api.slack.com/docs/interactive-message-field-guide#confirmation_fields) with a copy of the message text.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. My question is what is the link i need to but in that delete message so that the user can click on it to delete the message. (i don't want that link to be a call back to my backend which in turn calls chat.delete api). I want that link to directly open the delete message UI within the slack client.

Comment: AFAIK there is no official API for that. All the official deep linking is documented [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/deep-linking). Maybe you can find a hack for it, but that may not work for long.

Comment: Any particular reason why you do not want to call the backend?

Comment: Thanks. The reason is , i like the pop-up slack client presents when deleting a message. It clearly shows the message in a pop up window with a delete button. Its clean and user knows exactly which message they are deleting. Calling the backend means i cannot present that clean experience in the slack client.

Comment: I see. However, have you looked at the confirm messages for buttons? they also generate a modal pop-up and  look pretty much the same. see here: https://api.slack.com/docs/interactive-message-field-guide#confirmation_fields

Comment: Thanks. I agree the confirmation pop-up is a good alternative here.